# django-sass-processor: load sass_tags and load static

Tags: django

I'm wondering if {% load sass_tags %} is only for scss files, scss and css or all static files. For example which of those two examples would be correct:

Example 1:

```
{% load static %}
{% load sass_tags %}

<link href="{% sass_src 'scss.path' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="{% static 'img.path' %}">
```

Example 2:

```
{% load sass_tags %}

<link href="{% sass_src 'scss.path' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<img src="{% sass_src 'img.path' %}"
```

The latter seems to be working but I'd like to have a confirmation and a little bit more informations if anyone knows, I couldn't find much about this on the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It says the following on [**django-sass-processor** Github page](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor):

> This Django app provides a templatetag `{% sass_src 'path/to/file.scss' %}`, which can be used instead of the built-in templatetag `static`.

I think it's safe to assume that it was designed to be interchangeable with `static`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).